# Postfix : How to reject sender addresses that don't exist only for local domains

Tags: postfix

On my Postfix I'm trying to reject senders that use fake addresses from domains managed locally.
But I only want to perform the check for the local domains, not for every senders.

So if `example.com` is managed locally, I want to block `unknown_address@example.com` and let `known_address@example.com` and `anything@gmail.com` pass.

I looked into `smtpd_sender_restrictions` with `reject_unverified_sender` but I don't see how to do the check only for the local domains.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The parameter that you are looking for is [`smtpd_reject_unlisted_sender`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_reject_unlisted_sender)

> **smtpd_reject_unlisted_sender (default: no)**
>
> > Request that the Postfix SMTP server rejects mail from unknown sender addresses, even when no explicit `reject_unlisted_sender` access restriction is specified. This can slow down an explosion of forged mail from worms or viruses.
> >
> > An address is always considered "known" when it matches a *virtual(5)* alias or a *canonical(5)* mapping.
> >
> > - The sender domain matches *$mydestination*, *$inet_interfaces* or *$proxy_interfaces*, but the sender is not listed in *$local_recipient_maps*, and *$local_recipient_maps* is not null.
> > - The sender domain matches *$virtual_alias_domains* but the sender is not listed in $virtual_alias_maps.
> > - The sender domain matches *$virtual_mailbox_domains* but the sender is not listed in *$virtual_mailbox_maps*, and *$virtual_mailbox_maps* is not null.
> > - The sender domain matches *$relay_domains* but the sender is not listed in *$relay_recipient_maps*, and *$relay_recipient_maps* is not null.
> >
> > This feature is available in Postfix 2.1 and later.

You can enable it by specify `smtpd_reject_unlisted_sender = yes` in `main.cf`. Another way is put `reject_unlisted_sender` in `smtpd_*_restriction` stack.

---

Additional note: **what's difference between reject_unverified_sender  and reject_unlisted_sender?**

The difference of both method lies on how it perform verification.

- Postfix with parameter `reject_unverified_sender` will verifies the sender by telnet to remote MX server and perform unfinished SMTP transaction with recipient = unverified_sender. If the remote server doesn't reject the recipient, then postfix assume that the sender was verified. See [How address verification works](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_VERIFICATION_README.html#how) in postfix documentation.
- Postfix with parameter `reject_unlisted_sender` will verifies the sender by looking into valid recipient in [ALL domain classes](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_CLASS_README.html) (local, virtual alias, virtual mailbox and relay.

Comment: thank you this is exactly what I needed. I have another question : these checks apply to the sender but do you know how to do the same with the from field ? Because I receive spam from `sender = anything@gmail.com` with `from = unknown_address@example.com`

Comment: Sorry I don't know